# как работать с циклом while в qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, while

У меня есть функция с бесконечным циклом while внутри.
когда ее активирую, программа зависает.
Как можно запустить эту функцию в потоке в qt?

Comment: Класс QTimer предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html

Comment: @S.Nick то есть мне вместо цикла while юзать это таймер надо?

Comment: возможно. А может и отдельный поток. Мы не знаем Вашу задачу.

Comment: Я думаю, что эту проблему можно решить несколькими путями, в том чсиле через std::thread или QThread. А также, возможно, асинхронным кодом, но я в этом сам еще не разобрался))

Answer (score 0):

В долгие вычисления можно вставлять `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` чтоб сохранить отзывчивость интерфейса.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#the-event-loop-and-event-handling

Если код в вашем цикле спит - используйте таймеры

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#using-threads

Если там сеть - используйте readyread сигнал

Но бесконечные циклы нужно либо ложить в тред https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

Либо через QAbstractEventDispatcher проводить по одной итерации https://stackoverflow.com/a/14902417/2101808

Comment: QCoreApplication::processEvents() - это все таки костыль, а не решение.

Comment: @KoVadim код костыль, если в нем вечный цикл, а процесс евентс по моему не имеет в себе ничего плохого